# How to force to make a call to a restful service through http client?

Tags: rest, security, http, asp.net-web-api, httpclient

### Considerations:

First of all, I'm looking for a programmed/automated solution, not a -personal- solution. I'm afraid that this question has not a direct answer because technology, so I'll check any workaround to make this validation.

### Scenario:

I've a public RESTful service that my customers (third party applications) can consume.

It has authentication basic (in the header) and the POST has a parameter that contains a cyphered string in SHA-256 with the data sent in the other parameters, in order to validate the data.
This cyphered string is made by a hash-key provided by me, for every customer, because some customers are competitors between them.
Anyway...

### Problem:

Some customers are hitting the service directly from ajax, instead using a server-side http client. They are using the hashkey and the user/pass inside a javascript and beware my recommendations, there were no changes in their code. Because of this, we are not enabling them in our production environment.

### Question:

It's possible (and how can I do it?) validate if the call is from server-side without checking the URL referer?

Just as comment, I'm using Web Api 2.2 in C#, but I think I could handle making the code myself, so any answer without code will be useful anyway.

I'm afraid that there is not exists any answer, because the clients are the same, but any some workaround or idea will be preciated.

Sorry for my english and my poor knowledge in HTTP clients.

Comment: What about checking that there are no `Referer` header or that the `User-Agent` header does not contain any known browser name?

Comment: One point is you can protect your web api from ajax by checking whether request is ajax request or not by checking `Request.IsAjaxRequest` on `DelegatingHandler` , this could solve your problem partially, though. And yes, prefer the above comment from @Aurélien to add more restriction.

Comment: Thanks to both. They are really goods approachs!

Answer (score 0):

If you could describe why it is a problem that customers are using ajax - would be easier to guess general solution. For example you can create registration service where your customer must specify their IPs so you can whitelist them, or you can create client auth library which all customers should use.

Comment: Thanks for your ideas. I can't deny the IPs because are dynamics, and the library breaks the "service rest" principle.